# Python output is not redirected in order

Tags: python-3.x, formatting

I am trying to format output from the following Python 3.x script. Here is the function that I'm calling:

```
def daily_backup():
    # Header for /var/log/me/rsync_backup.log
    print(" ")
    print("#" * 75)
    print(get_dt())
    print("#" * 75)
    print(" ")

    # Update timestamp on backup file, notify user that backup has started
    Path("/var/log/me/rsync_backup_ran").touch()
    notify_send("Daily backup started","%s" % get_dt(),"info")

    # Every week, start over with current files
    if today_name != "Sunday":
        rsync_command = "rsync -avbH --stats --exclude-from=/home/me/bin/rsync_backup.ecl"
    else:
        rsync_command = "rsync -avH --stats --exclude-from=/home/me/bin/rsync_backup.ecl " \
                        "--delete --delete-excluded"


    # System configs, crontabs, installed software lists
    INSTALLED = "/home/me/.config/installed"
    if not os.path.isdir(INSTALLED):
        os.mkdir(INSTALLED)
    os.system("dpkg --get-selections > %s/installed-software" % INSTALLED)
    os.system("ls /home/me/.local/share/flatpak/app > %s/installed-flatpaks" % INSTALLED)
    os.system("rsync -avb /etc/apt/sources.list.d %s" % INSTALLED)
    os.system("rsync -avb /var/spool/cron %s" % INSTALLED)
    os.system("rsync -avb /etc/libvirt/qemu %s" % INSTALLED)

    # My data
    for i in range(3):
        cmd_format = "%s %s %s/%s/daily"
        cmd_info = (rsync_command, backup_paths[i], backup_root, backup_folders[i])
        os.system(cmd_format % cmd_info)

    notify_send("Daily backup ended","%s" % get_dt(),"info")

daily_backup()
```

The script works, except for that the header I create (at the top of the function) doesn't get printed until after all of the os.system calls. Is this normal behavior? How can I correct this?

Comment: Try to force the stdout as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/230774/5219160

Comment: Perfect - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a problem with the stdout.
Try to force it following this [SO previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-print-function/230774#230774)